# Is mouse over possible in three.js pointerlock controls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Understanding the fact that there would not be any cursor on the screen while using Point locker controls, is it possible to use mouse over somehow ? like a cube glows when my camera goes near or faces the cube geometry ?

Answer (score 0):

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html pointer lock will be possible too, you only need to define right vector.

Best to use 2 scenes.